# Updated Mac to El Capitan is asking for 4 digit PIN

Tags: macos

After updating my macOS 10.6.8 to El Capitan my Mac is asking for a 4 digit system PIN. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the prompt showing the full message and the window? It could be remote lock, firmware, or an iCloud prompt.

Comment: It is likely a 4 digit pin sent to an iOS device that is linked to your iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac has been locked via Find My iPhone. Whoever locked it has the code. Try logging into Find My iPhone on iCloud.com or on another Apple device and see if you can unlock it there.

If that doesn't work, somebody posted a (somewhat complex) work-around on the [mac-rumors forums](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-unlock-system-lock-pin-code.1438822/).

Last resort: go to Apple store with proof of purchase. They'll sort it out.